# Restricting memory usage for container vs restricting memory usage of JVM process inside the container? Which is better?

Tags: docker, jvm

I have a container and I am running 6 processes inside it. There are 3 other containers doing the same. If the size allocated to the group is 30 GB, I see that almost the entire RAM is being filled even though it takes only 25 GB on physical memory.

So I decided to restrict. What should I restrict? Should I restrict each container to 8 GB each? Or should I restrict RAM allocated to each process using `-XX:MaxRamFraction=xx`?

The first case is restricting a container and the second is restricting RAM allocated to each process. Which is better and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do both. Because JVM was pre-docker and does not work with cgroups (more info [here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/)), it does not 'see' the limits you put on your containers and tries to use more than it should. This has been fixed with Java9+ where the JVM is adapted to containers. The fix bellow will work for `java:8u172b111` and above.

1. Get a Docker image with `java:8u172b111` (e.g. `anapsix/alpine-java:8u172b11_jdk`)
2. Add `JAVA_OPTS` with the following values:

`-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2`

3. Limit the container memory. Now, JVM will use cgroups when calculating how much memory to consume.

One thing worth mentioning is that `-XX:MaxRAMFraction=2` should be tweaked according to your application, load and the number of threads running.

Guys from fabric8 have done [a great job](https://github.com/fabric8io-images/java/tree/84dddb5c8a72650e12c02d2056b86146edddac66) in making images that calculate the container memory and uses cca 50% of total memory as max allowed (I think that this can be adjusted also). And this works for java 7 as well.